# Magento not getting new order email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

We have installed Magento 1.9.2.4 in server.

We create new order in front-end not getting mail .It is issues only in front-end new order mail .

What is batter way to solved it .I checked other stack overflow issues related mail but not getting any solution .

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flow 2 Steps

**Step First :**

You have to set cron setting in your admin like below ,

> Goto : ADMIN -> SYSTEM -> ADVANCED -> SYSTEM -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks) - all the times are in minutes

set as per your need

[image]

**AND**

set cron file into you Cpanel

> Goto Cpanel -> Search " Cron Jobs " -> set you cron file

```
*/15 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null /Magento_root_path/cron.php
```

**Step Second :**

Just copy Template.php file into below path

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

And Make directory like below and paste there.

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

Now edit new Template.php and Goto line number : 407

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

Update as

```
if (!($this->hasQueue()) && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

Then please clear cache and check.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Download this extension and configure in your store.

[SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html)

and then goto

`System->configuration->Aschroder Extensions->SMTP Pro->Queue Configuration`

and set `Queue Usage` to `never`

Comment: I had installed extension but in log file getting error like : "Email not sent immediately, queued for sending." .How to resolved it.

Comment: @janmesh check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

starting 1.9.1 Magento uses cron queue to send transactional emails

make sure you enable cron on your server and add this line to crontab:

```
*/15 * * * * /bin/bash /path_to_magento_root/cron.sh
```

Comment: I already enable cron and also set cron file in our server.